# Command for listing all the possible values you can put in the yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

For example I want to list all the possible values I can put in the yaml file to create a `Pod`. I want to also look at the meanings of those values. e.g. in the container section you put in the details of the container

Comment: The [Kubernetes API one-pager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.25/) is a good document. Here's [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.25/#pod-v1-core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see field documentation for a Pod with

```
kubectl explain Pod
```

then you can look deeper into the structure with e.g. (or any other field)

```
kubectl explain Pod.spec
```